# How is it possible for a single sentence to have both a raising to subject verb and an object control verb?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, control, raising

Basically what it says in the title. How would a sentence with both be parsed?

Comment: Do you mean something like "Mark seems to have persuaded Mary to jump off a cliff."?

Comment: Yes! Exactly like that.

Comment: Why would it not be possible?

Comment: Given the example I provided showing that such sentences are grammatical, what kind of answer are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I was just interested in what such a sentence would look like in a tree.